# Load data from csv to table with existing data

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

There is a table that I have created and using LOAD FILE I have imported the rows of csv file X into table . Then data in table has been updated using UPDATE . 
Now I have the same csv file but with additional rows appended to it  and want only the additional rows to be inserted into the table . I dont want the updated rows in table to be modified when importing the csv to table .

Answer (score 0):

in this case you can follow  two steps:

1.first you have to identify the additional rows you can do this by comparing you csv file with your table data

2.After that you can update those additional data to database

Comment: I am talking about 10000 records !! I cant compare them one by one and also update the records one by one .I am looking for some easier way to do this .

Comment: what you are using for data instigation python or any other tools like pentaho?

Comment: then where you are using this . the solution i gave is eligible for pyhton or pentaho data integration tools